# Apache Ant - Hide/Secure Exec Task Arguments

Tags: ant

I want to execute Ant with the verbose option but I don't want the [arguments](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg) passed into the [Exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task to be displayed in situations where they are sensitive (i.e. user/password).

An example is where there's a connection to a database:

```
<exec executable="/bin/sh" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="/opt/blah/blah/bin/frmcmp_batch.sh Module=blah Userid=username/mypassword@blah Module_Type=blah"/>
</exec>
```

I don't want the arguments (specifically "Userid=username/mypassword@blah" showing up in the log).

What is the best way to hide/secure the arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I'm using the following workaround (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462732/make-ant-quiet-without-the-q-flag)) to hide "mypassword" but I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution?

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="test">

    <target name="test" depends="">
        <echo message="Testing..."/>

        <echo message="Turning verbose off... you should NOT see the arguments..."/>

        <script language="javascript">
            var logger = project.getBuildListeners().firstElement();
            // 2 works to turn off verbose
            logger.setMessageOutputLevel(2);
        </script>

        <exec dir="." executable="cmd">
            <arg line="/c dummy.bat mypassword"/>
        </exec>

        <echo message="Turning verbose on... you should see the arguments..."/>

        <script language="javascript">
            var logger = project.getBuildListeners().firstElement();
            // 3 works to turn verbose back on
            logger.setMessageOutputLevel(3);
        </script>

        <exec dir="." executable="cmd">
            <arg line="/c dummy.bat mypassword"/>
        </exec>

    </target>
</project>
```

dummy.bat

```
@echo off
echo dummy
```

Output

```
test:
     [echo] Testing...
     [echo] Turning verbose off... you should NOT see the arguments...
     [exec] dummy
     [echo] Turning verbose on... you should see the arguments...
     [exec] Current OS is Windows XP
     [exec] Executing 'cmd' with arguments:
     [exec] '/c'
     [exec] 'dummy.bat'
     [exec] 'mypassword'
     [exec]
     [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [exec] not part of the command.
     [exec] dummy
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to secure the password is not to use one :-) The following answer describes how to setup an SSH key:

- [Ant, download fileset from remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191713/ant-download-fileset-from-remote-machine/12206460#12206460)

The ANT [sshexec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) command supports a "keyfile" attribute.

## Update

Ahhh, scripting sudo can be a royal pain.

Here are solutions which have worked for me in the past.

1. Configure the user to not require a password. See "sudoers" file. In our setup we grant this special access to users in an admin user group. (See [Ant build.xml requires user input, but Eclipse has no tty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518508/ant-build-xml-requires-user-input-but-eclipse-has-no-tty/2518535#2518535))
2. Use SSH :-) Logging into the local machine is a perfectly valid way to automate a process. Enables us to use SSH keys to control access and possible to restrict the commands a user runs (via little known features of the authorized_keys file)
3. Use an automation tool like [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/). It has useful support for sudo built in. Passwords can be configured as options that are specified at runtime (GUI) but not saved anywhere. There is a command-line and REST API available for invoking jobs. This solution is possibly least useful, but I mention it because it's such a useful tool for automating operations tasks.

It seems you're concerned about the password appearing in a log file? My fixation is to never write my password down or hard-code it within a script....

Comment: Thank you for the response but this isn't what I'm looking for.  I'm not looking to run a command on a remote host.  I'm looking to execute a command on the host where the Ant script is running which requires sensitive arguments.  I've updated the question to explain this in greater detail.

Comment: Thank you again Mark but I'm already using NOPASSWD so I don't need to enter a password to execute the sudo command.  My question pertains to how to hide "Userid=username/mypassword@blah" in the example.  I've removed sudo from my example to clear this up.